# Logistic regression in Matlab, confused about the results

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, logistic-regression

I am testing out logistic regression in Matlab on 2 datasets created from the audio files:

- The first set is created via wavread by extracting vectors of each file: the set is 834 by 48116 matrix. Each traning example is a 48116 vector of the wav's frequencies.
- The second set is created by extracting frequencies of 3 formants of the vowels, where each formant(feature) has its' frequency range (for example, F1 range is 500-1500Hz, F2 is 1500-2000Hz and so on). Each training example is a 3-vector of the wav's formants.

I am implementing the algorithm like so:

Cost function and gradient:

```
h = sigmoid(X*theta);
J = sum(y'*log(h) + (1-y)'*log(1-h)) * -1/m;
grad = ((h-y)'*X)/m;

theta_partial =  theta;
theta_partial(1) = 0;

J = J + ((lambda/(2*m)) * (theta_partial'*theta_partial));
grad = grad + (lambda/m * theta_partial');
```

where X is the dataset and y is the output matrix of 8 classes.

Classifier:

```
 initial_theta = zeros(n + 1, 1);
    options = optimset('GradObj', 'on', 'MaxIter', 50);
    for c = 1:num_labels,
      [theta] = fmincg(@(t)(lrCostFunction(t, X, (y==c), lambda)), initial_theta, options);
      all_theta(c, :) = theta';
    end
```

where num_labels = 8, lambda(regularization) is 0.1

With the first set, MaxIter = 50, and I get ~99.8% classification accuracy.

With the second set and MaxIter=50, the accuracy is poor - 62.589928

I thought about increasing MaxIter to a larger value to improve the performance, however, even at a ridiculous amount of iterations, the result doesn't go higher than 66.546763. Changing of the regularization value (lambda) doesn't seem to influence the results in any better way.

What could be the problem? I am new to machine learning and I can't seem to catch what exactly causes this drastic difference. The only reason that obviously stands out for me is that the first set's examples are very long vectors, hence, larger amount of features, and the second set's examples are represented by short 3-vectors. Is this data not enough to classify the second set? If so, what can be done about it to achieve better classification results for the second set?

Comment: How are you measuring the accuracy?

Comment: @larsmans:
I calculate:
[values, p]= max(sigmoid(X*all_theta'), [], 2);
where all_theta is the matrix with 8 trained logistic regression prediction vectors(as in the original post)

and then:
mean(double(pred == y)) * 100);

Comment: You mean you're measuring it on the training set? In that case, this doesn't tell you much. You should measure accuracy on a test set to get more insight. Adding more features is pretty much guaranteed to increase the training set accuracy.

Comment: Thank you, now i implemented a code to randomly select 25% of the set as a test set, and i am trying it out.

Comment: Ok, let us know what comes out!

Comment: the highest results i get is ~72% accuracy of the training set and ~69% of the test set.  I also tried to run the set through a neural network and the results are similar, so i am pretty much at a loss what to do, except for trying to add more features.